# Open anchor href always in same tab

Tags: javascript, html, href, anchor, target

I've been struggling with a problem for a couple of days, and I was wondering if there's any way of opening an anchor href link always at the same tab, but this tab has to be a different one from the tab where the anchor is located.

It's ok if I have to use JavaScript instead of pure HTML attributes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `target="tabname"` in the anchor. It will reuse the tab with that name if it already exists.

Comment: are you using `target blank`?